# Lucene facet request on list - missing elements

Tags: solr, lucene, hibernate-search

Let's say that we have entity which have a list of other subentity.
If there is more than one element in list, facet request doesnt count all of them for each group but only for random(probably there is some mechanism) property.

```
FacetingRequest categoryFacetingRequest = qBuilder.facet()
                .name("districtFaceting").onField("address.districtId")
               .discrete().orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.COUNT_DESC)
               .includeZeroCounts(true).createFacetingRequest();

class Base {
    List<Address> adresses = ...
}

class Address {

     @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES)
     public String getDistrictId() {
        return this.districtId;
     }

}
```

In case of `Base` will have more than one address, facet request will return only one count for random `district` id. Other are no incremented.

Is there any solution to have correct results ?

Answer (score 2):

To use faceting requests, the fields on which you want to use faceting should be annotated accordingly with `@Facet`.

Your code snippet is missing this annotation, which could explain the issue. Could you try adding a `@Facet` annotation on `getDiscritctId`?

If you already have one, could you please expand your code sample to include all the relevant annotations that are present in your code? (`@Facet`, `@Indexed`, `@IndexedEmbedded`, ...)

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-faceting-entity

Comment: Probably that's the reason, thank you for answer. All models are build with @ Indexed and @ IndexedEmbedded annotations. Probably this missing @ Facet makes result incorrect. I will check this soon.